# mysql return results from update

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I want to select a bunch of rows from a mysql database and update the viewed attribute of those once selected (this is a kind of 'I have read these' flag).

Initially I did something like this:

```
update (
        select a, b, c
        from mytable
        where viewed = '0'
        )
set viewed = '1';
```

This selects the rows nicely and updates their viewed attribute as required. But it does not return the selected rows from the subquery.

Is there a clause I can add, or perhaps I need to store the subquery, etc...? I did consider a transaction but I ended up with the same problem. I have not tried a stored procedure...

Please can someone advise / point me in the right direction on how to do what I do above but in addition return the selected tables from the subquery?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

As pointed out by @Barmar, @a_horse_with_no_name, @fancyPants and @George Garchagudashvil...

In MySQL you have to use two statements to select and update, and not a nested statement as in my initial post, if you want to return the selected rows.

e.g.

```
begin;
  select a, b, c
    from mytable
    where viewed = '0';
  update mytable
    set viewed = '1'
    where viewed = '0';
commit;
```

thanks guys.

Comment: An UPDATE and a SELECT are two different things. They have to be two separate queries. What 'problem' are you trying to solve?

Comment: UPDATE updates, SELECT selects. You can't do both at once.

Comment: SELECT the rows `WHERE viewed = 0` first, then do the update.

Comment: I am trying to reduce a select followed by an update to one query - to be efficient. Also I need the setting of the viewed attribute to be atomic as it is a 'read' flag. Don't forget I need the select results - this is the problem with the above.

Comment: why you wanna try select and update at same query? Can't you do what you trying to do in 2 steps?

Comment: If I use two steps e.g. select then update I may get issues because this is not atomic (I have multiple clients etc...). I considered a transaction e.g. begin; select... update... commit; but this does not return me the rows fro the select. Also I am concerned with efficiently as I scale up with 100s of cleints.

Comment: @Barmar: you can't do both in *MySQL*. You _can_ do that in other DBMS without any problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: So is my only option to write a trigger in the DB, so when I select those rows the DB changed the viewed attributes for me?

Comment: You can not write a trigger that is fired when you run a `select`. Your only option with MySQL is to use two statements.

Comment: A transaction is the way to go. Why does a transaction not work for you? Please describe more thoroughly.

Comment: @fancyPants: Well may be I did not use a transaction properly?

As noted above I did something like 'begin; select... update... commit' whereas this processed the rows correctly, it did not return to be the rows processed - I guess this is because the update is the last statement...

Comment: What do you mean with "it did not return to be the rows processed"? Please add much more detail. You know that you might not see what a transaction does from the outside until it's commited? Have a look at isolation levels, maybe you chose the wrong one.

Comment: @fancyPants: Ah ha I've made a mistake - the transaction does work! Thanks for keeping the thread going as it forced me to 'see the wood through the trees'. I will post the actual working transaction and mark thread as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a simple function:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `mydb`.`updateMytable`$$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    FUNCTION `mydb`.`updateMytable`() RETURNS TEXT 

    BEGIN

        SET @updated := '';

        UPDATE mytable
            SET viewed = 1
        WHERE viewed = 0
            AND ( 
                SELECT @updated := CONCAT_WS(',', @updated, id) 
            ) != ''
        ;

        RETURN TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @updated); 

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

which updates tables and returns concatenated ids.

From php you call this:

```
SELECT mydb.updateMytable()
```

and you get ids in a stirng: `1,2,7,54,132` etc...

**Update:**

my function is returning string containing comma separated ids:
`'1,5,7,52,...'` these ids are only which would have been updated during the function call,

better php-mysql example would be (you may and would use PDO):

```
$query = "SELECT mydb.updateMytable()";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$ids = explode(',', $arr[0]);

// now you can do whatever you want to do with ids
foreach ($ids as $id) 
{
    echo "Hoorah: updated $id\n";
}
```

also remember to change `mydb` and `mytable` according to your database names

**Final**

because you need more complex functionality, simply run two query:

**First run:**

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM mytable
WHERE viewed = 0
```

**Next run:**

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET viewed = 1 
WHERE viewed = 0
```

Comment: Thanks George. I am thinking a function, stored procedural or trigger is the way to go, but can't help thinking this should be possible with some simple alterations from my original query.

That said I am not sure in your function what you are returning (TBH I had to lookup some stuff :) )? Please explain a little?

Comment: I've added some more explanation, it returns just single string column, you can easily manipulate it later as you want, hope I've made better sense for the code:))

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I am afraid this does not do want I want at all - perhaps my initial example is lacking.

This returns a series of id's representing the rows updated. I want the rows updated as per my subquery above e.g. 'select a, b, c etc...'.