# MySQL update column and return value from another column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

The task is currently being run in a CRON job to SELECT `code_id` and `created_date` from the `reset_pw_log` where the `status = 'A'ctive`.

Then I step through the results and set a variable named `$pw_key_code = code_id`.

Then determine if the `created_date` is over 60 minutes old. If YES, I UPDATE `reset_pw_log` and SET `status = 'E'xpired` WHERE `code_id = $pw_key_code` and `status = 'A'`.

This is currently working perfectly as it is.

What I would like to do is after I UPDATE the `status` of the record based on a `code_id` to `'E'xpired`, I would like to return the value of the `mem_id` column of that same record, so I can use it as a key to do an INSERT into another table.

Hopefully that is clear enough

This is the update...  is there a way to edit it to return the `mem_id` from that record?

```
$sql_update = "
     UPDATE reset_pw_log
     SET status = 'E'
     WHERE code_id = '".$pw_key_code."'
     AND status = 'A'
";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does not have to be fancy you could do it sequentally what would be easy to read and maintain:

```
$sql_update = " UPDATE reset_pw_log SET status = 'E' WHERE code_id = '".$pw_key_code."' AND status = 'A' ";

$new_id = "SELECT mem_id FROM reset_pw_log WHERE code_id = '".$pw_key_code."' AND status = 'E'"

-- do insert with new_id
```

Comment: Hi Otto, Thank you for your response.

While that would accomplish what I need to get done in the end, I was hoping someone could educate me on whether it could be done in a single update query that would also return the required data in response.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054844/mysql-return-results-from-update#25056136
Otherwise you could at least use begin transaction/commit to do update and select within one transaction.

Comment: Thanks again otto for the follow up...

I decided that based on all the research I've done, even though apparently someone doesn't think I've done any, I've decided to just go with the second query.  In fact I have already implemented it and tested it... and it is working fine...

I ask questions because I want to find out if someone has come up with solutions that I haven't seen yet...

Thanks again... Guess you get the green check mark on this one.